# How to sort a large text file and search for duplicates with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a relatively large text file (2,46 GB). It contains one phrase in every line. I have to sort it, and make sure it does not contain duplicates, and unnecessary spaces at the start, or at the end of each line.

I found a solution to the sorting problem. I use Sublime Text 3, and it has a sort function.

I used php `trim` to cut off spaces, but I can not make any further progress.

Comment: You need to be more specific, and you need to show what you have tried so far -- like what are the sorting criteria?

Comment: Use Microsoft excel, it is perfect for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

Sorting through a 2.5GB file when not in CLI mode (?), you will likely either run out of memory, or execution time. Given that you point to Sublime as a non-PHP solution, I give you my non-PHP suggestion as a point of departure. Please specify your goals for a more specific answer. On a Linux(-like) system, you may be able to do the following:

`awk '{$1=$1};1' file.txt | sort > output.txt`

The `awk` command will trim any leading and trailing whitespace. The trimmed output is then piped to `sort`, which will sort things for you. The final result is output to `output.txt`.